# Why is "it" used instead of "he/she" for human being in "it becomes a wise and virtuous man…"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, personal-pronouns, dummy-it

> Now this relaxation of the mind from work consists on playful words or deeds. Therefore **it becomes a wise and virtuous man** to have recourse to such things at times.
>
> —Thomas Aquinas

Is the bold phrase an idiom of the old times? Because I think we will use **He/She** instead of **it** for "a wise man", if we like to rephrase it today: He who has recourse to such things, becomes a wise man.

Comment: It is a current phrase, not one of previous times.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an erroneous premise that has now been clarified by an answer.

Comment: The example is off but the headline question holds some interest. Actual examples include *A Midsummer Night's Dream* 2.1.172 ("The juice of it, on sleeping eyelids laid, / Will make or man or woman madly dote / Upon the next live creature that **it** sees") and the much-memed line from *The Silence of the Lambs,* "It rubs the lotion on its skin."

Comment: As you see, the verb *becomes* is not used as "turns into," but suits.

Comment: @Anton I CV-d as well as I believe the it-cleft is in itself of ELL standard, and the trickier aspects have been covered here before. I don't know who re-opens questions / squashes CVs without any explanation.

Answer (score 4):

No. The sense of the passage is not "He/she becomes a wise and virtuous man" (?).

**It** refers to **having recourse to such things** (relaxation from work), which Aquinas says is **becoming** (definition 2 [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/becoming)) to a wise person.

Comment: Actually *it* is not a referring pronoun here, it's a meaningless dummy used to fill the subject slot in such extraposition constructions. See here: [Expletive pronouns in subcategorised positions](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/Postal-Pullum88.pdf) if you would like a high-faulting explanation of why this must be the case.

Answer (score 3):

"It" is here the neutral pronoun; it is used in a grammatical turn called "*extraposition of a subject clause*" (Quirk, *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, § **2.59** **Grammatical highlighting**).

> The role of the anticipatory pronoun "it" […] is essentially a structural one in the sense that it carries virtually no information in itself, but merely
> supplies the structural requirement for an initial subject. (Its semantic
> function, in so far as it has one, is merely to signal that the content of the
> subject is expressed in a later position in the same sentence.) A somewhat
> parallel role is performed by the introductory word "there" in EXISTENTIAL
> sentences.

The usual form is as follows, where "*to have recourse to such things at times*" is the subject clause.

- Therefore, to have recourse to such things at times becomes a wise and virtuous man.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/become?q=become)) **become** verb [transitive, no passive] (not used in the progressive tenses)
> **become somebody (formal)** to be suitable for somebody
>
> • Such behaviour did not become her.

Comment: I would have thought "It is becoming ..." might be seen as progressive, though perhaps other parsing is possible

Comment: This is another term for (or type of) "dummy it", right?

Comment: @Laurel That is a usable term; see for instance the reference given by [Araucaria-Him](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/614855/is-it-possible-to-use-it-instead-of-he-she-for-human-being-in-some-cases/614859?noredirect=1#comment1563110_614856) above, and search for "dummy". (http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/Postal-Pullum88.pdf)